# Are the unread count visual styles appropriate?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, user-experience

When you have an unread inbox, you get a **bright red** notification in the menu bar:

[image: unread counts]

That frequently frightens me. I'm not a UX expert, but that bright red says to me **warning**, **danger** or something along those lines. I don't *think* there's any reason to interpret inbox msgs as ***BAD NEWS***, but that is what the styling conveys to me.

Compare that to the **green** achievement indicator, which seems much more appropriate.

Just to provide some contrast, perhaps a neutral blue would seem less *dangerous* and  more appropriate:

[image]

Comment: Inbox notifications are items that typically require action. Red is the best colour to draw your eye and have you take an action. Just my opinion.

Comment: I get alarmed when I see the red indicator on Stack Overflow in particular. I think part of the issue is that it's in almost the same place as the green reputation indicator, so especially if you don't have any new reputation points, so it can appear that the indicator has changed from green to red, which looks like something usually good has turned bad.

Comment: @MarcStober that green/red juxtaposition may have a lot to do with it.

Comment: Red can also just mean **important**, and it's been used with that meaning for a long time, [particularly for notification badges](https://www.google.ch/search?q=notification+badge&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 8):

I am not a UX expert either, but speaking as a longtime heavy user of the site...

Red doesn't imply ***"danger!"*** to me. Rather, it says ***"you should click here because there's important targeted and timely info!"***  Which is exactly what the global inbox delivers.

Where the site does have blue markers, in the user profile, I find myself never bothering to notice or click, even as a person who insists upon having no unread messages in my email, ever.

[image: I never click these blue markers]

**If the `Responses` had a red marker, I might click it...**

On the homepage, a blue marker is already in use for the `Featured` (bounty questions) tab.  This area is important, probably worth clicking on, but not *specifically curated and targeted for me*.

[image: Featured tab with blue indicator]

Likewise, a light blue indicator is used for far less important notifications during Winterbash each year, when notifying of a newly earned hat. (Albeit on a *different* snowflake indicator icon)

So, red feels appropriate for timely and potentially actionable notifications specifically curated for an individual user, where blue is already being used as a callout for important, but not user-targeted or timely numbers on the home page.

Comment: I think any variance from the base grays in the menu bar is eye catching and says "click me".  Maybe the UX experts will start weighing in :)